# Adding multiple rows of information with 1 save control

Tags: excel, forms

Good day.
I am wanting to create a user form in excel where 1 portion of the data will remain constant but other entered data will be added on multiple rows.

For example. The end result will show a table like this

```
 Operator      Lic#       Stage      Top        Bottom

 Chevron       12349        1        5000        5010 Chevron      
 12349        2        4910        4950 Chevron       12349        3   
 4850        4905
```

My thoughts were to have a multi page user form with the first tab being the "Header data" (The data that would be duplicated at the start of each row. The "operator" and "Lic#" in the above example).
Another tab(s) will be the other data with enough text boxes to accommodate all of the multiple rows of data. The "Stage", "Top" and"Bottom". (if the max # of "stages" would be 10. I would have 10 text boxes ready to populate for each column name).

I am new with coding. I would know how enter all of the data into 1 row but I would like the code to recognize that each unique "stage" needs to go into the next blank row, with all of the populated "header" data before it. And also recognize that if the stages stops at 8, to NOT create two additional rows with blank data.
I would imagine this would be a looping statement based on the stage #???.

Would really love some help on this.....thank you in advance.

Comment: My apologies...My above question does not show how the table would look. It put it all on one row. If you could imagine the new rows of data starting with the word "Chevron" for 3 rows of data. The stage #'s are the ones after "12349". The "Operator", "Lic#", "Stage", "Tp" and "Bottom" would be the table headers in excel.

Comment: Please edit your question if you have additional information. Do not post that in a comment. Nobody wants to read a wall of comments to figure out what you're asking. You can copy and paste cells right from Excel.

Comment: On this site programmers find help. Programmers may be novice or expert, occasional or professional, but they must write code. If you don't write code you are not a programmer and you can't find help here.